# Different HMAC for CryptoJS and VB

Tags: javascript, cryptography, hmac, basic

I have to generate a HMACSHA256 in Visual Basic. Problem is, that I didnt receive the correct HMAC and get different HMACS

InputData = Test\nTest\n\nTest
secret = c39ff802b43a01c08ea759750c41d7d4bac6b1b884b3864d640b577cf1dca21a

HMACa = 330c55857e5ff197a407a9dcd41bbf03a2e8de0b351aba9a405139919b3cae57
HMACb = f701ea7028f20df11a52bee297a336de212655a8bad01d848eeaa87d0f76ee5e

JS(CryptoJS) ->    HMACa (Tested directly)
PY           ->    HMACa (Tested directly)

JS(jsSHA)    ->    HMACb (Tested under: liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/HMAC/)
C#/VB        ->    HMACb (Tested directly)

**Why do i get different HMAC's and what can i do to get HMACa in VB/C#??**

Here is my VB Code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim sToHash As String = "Test\nTest\n\nTest"
    Dim sKey As String = "c39ff802b43a01c08ea759750c41d7d4bac6b1b884b3864d640b577cf1dca21a"
    Console.WriteLine(getHMAC(sToHash, sKey))
End Sub

Function getHMAC(ToHash As String, SecretKey As String) As String
    Dim aoText() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ToHash)
    Dim aoKey() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecretKey)

    Using oHmac As New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(aoKey)
        Dim sHash As Byte() = oHmac.ComputeHash(aoText)
        Return ByteToString(sHash)
    End Using
End Function

Function ByteToString(buff As Byte()) As String
    Dim getbinary As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To buff.Length - 1
        getbinary += buff(i).ToString("X2")
    Next
    Return (getbinary).ToLower
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier than intended. VB/C# can't Encode '\n' as NewLine. In World of VisualBasic you have to write vbLf to Indicate a NewLine in a String

So the correct InputString is now: 
"Test" + vbLf + "Test" + vbLf + vbLf + "Test"

Result => HMACa

Thanks anyway